# SQL School Homework, write a SELECT which returns

Tags: sql, join, select, window-functions, rank

Write a SELECT, which returns the name of the fifth album for each band. If the band does not have a fifth album, there should be nothing on it. If a band has more albums in one year, let the lexicographic arrangement by album name apply. The result should include the name of the band and the name of the album, ranked lexicographically according to the name of the band in ascending order (from A to Z).

[image: DATA MODEL FOR THE TASK]

My solution which is not correct, because I could not fill the fifth album with NULL value.

```
SELECT brand_name, album_name
FROM (
    SELECT b.name AS brand_name, a.name AS album_name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY b.name ORDER BY a.release_year) AS rank
    FROM bands AS b
    JOIN albums AS a ON a.band_id = b.id
  ) tmp
WHERE rank = 5
```

My result:
[image: My result]
Correct result:
[image: Correct result]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "IT'S HOMEWORK!"  If you don't understand a homework assignment, don't go to the Internet ... go to your teacher.  The purpose is for YOU to figure it out on your own, and if the teacher's explanations were not clear enough (for you and therefore undoubtedly for other students also), (s)he needs to know that.  You're shooting yourself in the foot if you look for some stranger on the Internet to give you the answer.

Comment: Hint: `LIMIT` ...

Comment: There's guidance for asking about homework questions on Meta, [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), and this question falls clearly inside the lines. As for trusting strangers on the internet, the irrelevant hint regarding `LIMIT` is why one should be cautious.

Comment: Don't post images of text. Better hint: Left Join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rank albums in a subquery, then `left join` in the outer query:

```
SELECT b.name brand_name, a.name album_name
FROM bands b
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        band_id, 
        name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY band_id ORDER BY release_year) AS rn
    FROM albums
) a ON a.band_id = b.id AND a.rn = 5
```